# Eddited XML File with certain element

Tags: python, xml

So in python I need to read and write to an XML database. I have the reading part done but I having trouble finding a way to only write data to a node with a specific element.

This should clear up things

```
 <team>
    <number>78</number>
    <matches_played>0</matches_played>
    <matches_played>0</matches_played>
    <start_position>1</start_position>
    <preloaded_ball>0</preloaded_ball>
    <high_goals_made_auto>0</high_goals_made_auto>
    <low_goals_made_auto>0</low_goals_made_auto>
    <shots_missed_auto>0</shots_missed_auto>
    <hot_goal_bonus_auto>0</hot_goal_bonus_auto>
    <moved_bonus_auto>0</moved_bonus_auto>
    <high_goals_made_tel>0</high_goals_made_tel>
    <low_goals_made_tel>0</low_goals_made_tel>
    <shots_missed_tel>0</shots_missed_tel>
    <balls_received_tel>0</balls_received_tel>
    <balls_passed_tel>0</balls_passed_tel>
    <truss_shots_tel>0</truss_shots_tel>
    <catches_tel>0</catches_tel>


</team>

<team>
    <number>195</number>
    <matches_played>0</matches_played>
    <matches_played>0</matches_played>
    <start_position>1</start_position>
    <preloaded_ball>0</preloaded_ball>
    <high_goals_made_auto>0</high_goals_made_auto>
    <low_goals_made_auto>0</low_goals_made_auto>
    <shots_missed_auto>0</shots_missed_auto>
    <hot_goal_bonus_auto>0</hot_goal_bonus_auto>
    <moved_bonus_auto>0</moved_bonus_auto>
    <high_goals_made_tel>0</high_goals_made_tel>
    <low_goals_made_tel>0</low_goals_made_tel>
    <shots_missed_tel>0</shots_missed_tel>
    <balls_received_tel>0</balls_received_tel>
    <balls_passed_tel>0</balls_passed_tel>
    <truss_shots_tel>0</truss_shots_tel>
    <catches_tel>0</catches_tel>


</team>
```

As you see both are `<team>` and they all have a `<number>` how do I only edit elements in 
`<number>78</number>`?

Comment: What parser do you prefer?

Comment: @alecxe i use `xml.etree.ElementTree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple generator expression you can use to find the team element that contains the number element with text = `78`:

```
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
team = next(team for team in tree.iter('team') 
            for number in team.iter('number') 
            if number.text == '78')

team.find('.//high_goals_made_tel').text = "I've changed"
print ET.tostring(tree)
```

Where `data` is your xml string.

And, just FYI, the solution using `lxml` looks much easier, because it has full xpath support:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import XMLParser

data = """..."""

tree = etree.fromstring(data, parser=XMLParser())
team = tree.xpath('.//number[text()="78"]/..')[0]
team.find('high_goals_made_tel').text = "I've changed"

print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Comment: can i interchange lxml and ElementTree?

Comment: @ExcelledProducts I've included the solution using `lxml`, please check.

Comment: for your ElementTree how can i put that into a loop so I can set the text?

Comment: @ExcelledProducts what do you want to change?

Comment: so like I want to edit hig_goals_made_tel only in the <tream> of <number> 78